# Why an iterative algorithm for finding epsilon in python takes virtually roughly 0 seconds?

Tags: python

Looking for python epsilon (with out any library) I coded:

```
import time
start = time.time()
x=1.0

while 1+x/2 != 1.0:
    x/=2.0
print x
print time.time() - start
```

And I get the outputs:

```
2.22044604925e-16
5.79357147217e-05
```

I don't think answer about the slightest time is just because is that fast

Comment: why would it take more time?

Comment: it's O(lg(n)), which doesn't grow much as you increase n

Comment: The division by two gives such order, right?

Comment: That's probably over 100k clock cycles to do 200 operations. It's actually slow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) module. It's great for evaluating code that takes very little time to run:

```
import timeit

def algorithm():
    x=1.0
    while 1+x/2 != 1.0:
        x/=2.0
    #print x  # disabled so i don't get 100,000 prints

timeit.timeit(algorithm, number=100000) # 100,000 times!
```

Output (for me):

```
0.95662535660580161
```

Comment: Note that this means that the loop takes about `0.956/100000` seconds, including function call overhead, not that it secretly takes almost a second and a better timing method reveals the secret horrible slowness.

Answer (score 3):

> double-precision binary floating-point format
>
> Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)

If you add a loop counter, you will see that it gets executed only 52 times.